# db operation exception handling in R

Tags: r, sqlite, exception, try-catch

I am using the following function to select values from a table.Table name is given as the parameter to that function.If the table does not exist an error generated and the execution is stoped.I want to do something if the table is not found.Is it possible in R? something like try-catch exception ?

```
library('RSQLite')
getData <- function(portfolio){
  lite <- dbDriver("SQLite", max.con = 25)
  db <- dbConnect(lite, dbname = "portfolioInfo.db")
  res <- dbSendQuery(db, paste("SELECT * from ",portfolio," ",sep=""))
  data <- fetch(res)
  return (data)
}
getData("table1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to check the class of the data that is returned.

I am not familiar with RSQLite but I guess it will return a dataframe if the table is found and a text error when not?

So a possibility would be to check whether or not an error is raised:

```
checkQueryResult<-function(data){
    if(class(data)=='data.frame') cat('SQL execution worked!')
    else cat('Something went wrong, table does not exist?')
    }

checkQueryResult(getData("table1"))
```

But maybe the RSQLite package already has error handling stuff built in?